# Backbone Collection from JSON is undefined

Tags: json, backbone.js, collections

I'm beginner on Backbone so the solution could be... simple.
I try to get data from a JSON when I instantiate my Main View but the console tells me "TypeError: d.collection is undefined".

Here's my code :

### Init

```
var app = {
    init : function(){
        this.instance = new app.ViewsApp();
        this.router = new app.Router();
        Backbone.history.start(); 
    }
};
app.init();
```

### Model

```
app.Step = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

### Collection

```
app.StepsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : app.Step,
    url : 'content.json',
    parse : function(response){
        console.log(response);
        return response;
    }
});
```

### View

```
// MAIN VIEW
app.ViewsApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#myApp',
    initialize : function(){
         this.collection = new app.StepsList();
         //this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', '');
        console.log(this.collection);
        this.collection.fetch({
            reset : true,
            success : function(){console.log('json ok');},
            error : function(){console.log('json problem');}
        });
    }
});
```

Do you have a solution or some advices ?

Comment: have you checked the sequence of Definition of Collection and instant creation?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean ?
now I reload my  Home project I have a "json ok" on console.log but when I try to listen with this :
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.datas);
I have this other error : "TypeError: this.listenTo is not a function" how it is possible ?! There is no change in my code...

Comment: Yes. That happens because, the "this" object in "this.listenTo" does not have the scope of the View. Either bind it to the scope of View or pass the scope as an argument (not recommended).

Comment: There is no such line containing `d.collection` in shared code. In comments you're saying `"TypeError: this.listenTo is not a function"`. Please [edit] and update the question explaining what exactly is the error, and add all the code necessary to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included old librairies so with no "listenTo" support... my bad... Resolved. Thx for paying attention to my problem!